# How can I find min and max values in a (multidimensional?) array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

**I have an array that is created like this in Swift**

```
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell, TKChartDelegate {

    var xAxisDates = [] --> filled with fetch from Coredata
    var yAxisValues = [] --> filled with fetch from Coredata

    var maximumValue = maxElement(yAxisValues)   -> error: TableViewCell.Type' does not have a member named 'yAxisValues'

func chart (){
    var dataPointSeries = [TKChartDataPoint]()

    for var i = 0; i < xAxisDates.count; ++i {
    dataPointSeries.append(TKChartDataPoint(x: xAxisDates[i], y: yAxisValues[i]))

    println(dataPointSeries)
    }
<--more code setting up the chart-->
}
```

**The console output is this:**

[x = '2014-11-25 02:00:00 +0000', y = '61', name = '(null)',  x = '2014-11-25 02:00:00 +0000', y = '57', name = '(null)']

I would like to find the max and min value of the y's.

I have tried maxElement(dataPointSeries(x)), but that does not work.  Any idea how I could do this? I can't seem to find any solution.

Comment: I don't know what language you're righting in, but I'm pretty sure you can't have an array with keys sharing the same name...

Comment: What exactly are x = '2', y = '61', etc. Are you trying to create a dictionary? Are they supposed to be strings?

Comment: which language you are using ?

Comment: Language is swift,the x values are NSDates.  The output is straight from the output

Comment: Why are you even going through the multi-dimensional array. You just want the max and min on `yAxisValues`?

Comment: Yes indeed, but when I try that (var maximumValue = maxElement(yAxisValues)) I get error: TableViewCell.Type does not have a member named 'yAxisValues'

Comment: I think there is more to your code than you are showing us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you want is the minimum and maximum values of the y elements, there is no need to consider this in the context of the multi-dimensional array. All you need do is:

```
let minimumYValue = minElement(yAxisValues)
let maximumYValue = maxElement(yAxisValues)
```

Comment: I tried that but but I get error: TableViewCell.Type does not have a member named 'yAxisValues'

Comment: @karlml You have to put this code within a "func" to utilize your global variables.

Comment: Thank you!  Unfortunately this gave me the error code:  Generic parameter 'R.Generator.Element' cannot be bound to non-@objc protocol type 'AnyObject'